# Insert Missing Month Values as 0 in Python List

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a list:

```
t = [['01-2012', 3], 
     ['02-2012', 2], 
     ['03-2012', 9], 
     ['04-2012', 1], 
     ['05-2012', 6], 
     ['06-2012', 40], 
     ['07-2012', 3], 
     ['08-2012', 282], 
     ['09-2012', 3], 
     ['12-2012', 6],
     ['02-2013', 16],
     ['04-2013', 9]]
```

I need to add all the missing [mm-yyyy, value] elements on their respective places within this list as [mm-yyyy, 0], so as to smooth the time series across all the missing months. Any guesses?

Right now what I am doing is calculating all the 0 values as follows:

```
total_items = [0]*12

for d in t:
    month = int(d[0].split('-')[0], 10)
    total_items[month-1] = d[1]
```

so this gives me all the values including the ones for missing months as 0, but I am not sure how to generate the corresponding mm-yyyy element for them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I notice that this is tagged numpy. Do you actually have a 2D array that you want to expand, rather than a list of lists? If so, converting it to a list is definitely not the best way to start. (And you may want to have a look at pandas, too.)

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler solution is to just iterate through the months and years in the range, and add the ones that are missing.

---

This would be easier if you used a `dict` instead of a `list` of two-element `list`s, so let's do that first.

```
data = dict(t)
for year in range(2012, 2014):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        mmyyyy = '{:02}-{:04}'.format(month, year)
        data.setdefault(mmyyyy, 0)
```

---

Then, if you want to convert it back to your original format, that's easy too:

```
t = [[k, v] for k, v in data.items()]
```

---

And if you need them sorted by date… Well, your month-first format makes that ugly, but it's certainly doable:

```
t = sorted(t, key=lambda kv: kv[0][3:] + kv[0][:2])
```

But, as that last line shows, it's often a whole lot easier to deal with dates as date objects rather than strings. So, you might want to consider that as well.

---

However, maybe rather than inserting the 0s, you'd be better off just keeping 0 as a default and processing them by looping over years and months instead of by looping over the collection?

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding t.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%m-%Y')) to what you just wrote solves the entire issue. Many thanks. :-)

Comment: One more thing sir: How to achieve this when year is only a single year..lets say 2012 only.?

Comment: @khan: Then remove the `for year in…` loop, and instead just use the year 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) library for such things

```
t = [['01-2012', 3], 
     ['02-2012', 2], 
     ['03-2012', 9], 
     ['04-2012', 1], 
     ['05-2012', 6], 
     ['06-2012', 40], 
     ['07-2012', 3], 
     ['08-2012', 282], 
     ['09-2012', 3], 
     ['12-2012', 6],
     ['02-2013', 16],
     ['04-2013', 9]]
t = array(t, dtype=object)
s = Series(t[:, 1], index=pd.to_datetime(t[:, 0])).convert_objects().sort_index()
s.resample('MS').fillna(0)
```

to get

```
2012-01-01      3
2012-02-01      2
2012-03-01      9
2012-04-01      1
2012-05-01      6
2012-06-01     40
2012-07-01      3
2012-08-01    282
2012-09-01      3
2012-10-01      0
2012-11-01      0
2012-12-01      6
2013-01-01      0
2013-02-01     16
2013-03-01      0
2013-04-01      9
Freq: MS, dtype: float64
```

Note that I've arbitrarily used the first of the month here.